# Sort stage with European Date Format

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection structured like this:

```
_id    name    date
1      Dave    15.02.2014
2      Dave    24.01.2014
3      Dave    20.01.2014
...
```

I need to aggregate the `first` and the `last` date for every `name`, such that I end up with something like this:

```
_id    name    First_Date  Last_Date
1      Dave    20.01.2014  15.02.2014
...
```

I was trying the following query, but it did not work out well, the fie

```
db.users.aggregate([
  {   "$sort": {
          "date": 1
  }},
  {   "$group":  {
          "_id": 1,
          "name": {"$first": "$name"},
          "First_Date": {"$first": "$date"},
          "Last_Date": {"$last": "$date"}
  }}
  ]
```

Question: How can this be achieved with a mongo query?

Comment: What you really mean is that the "dates" are actually "strings" right? So what "really" should happen here is that you fix your dates by actually parsing them into proper BSON `Date` Objects. Apart from being useful, and also sorting correctly and filtering correctly in ranges, the storage size is also considerably less than the length of your current strings.

Comment: And if you thought you needed a string for "european format", then that is not true. The whole point of a BSON date is so it can be used as a natural date type directly in your programming language of choice. All of which will have extensive options to format a date for a given locale. Use `Date` types. Not strings. You can "force" things to work how you ask here, but you can do it "easily" by simply using the correct storage type.

Comment: @NeilLunn I look into it. Imported this data from a csv via `mongoimport`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do it how the data is presently formed, you need to re-order the string to a "lexical" or `"yyyymmdd" format to allow it to sort:

```
db.users.aggregate([
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$name",
    "first_date": {
      "$min": {
        "$concat": [
           { "$substrCP": [ "$date", 6, 4 ] },
           { "$substrCP": [ "$date", 3, 2 ] },
           { "$substrCP": [ "$date", 0, 2 ] }
         ]
      }
    },
    "last_date": {
      "$max": {
        "$concat": [
           { "$substrCP": [ "$date", 6, 4 ] },
           { "$substrCP": [ "$date", 3, 2 ] },
           { "$substrCP": [ "$date", 0, 2 ] }
         ]
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

Noting that for 
Depending on your MongoDB version then that is [`$substrCP`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/substrCP/) for Modern releases or [`$substr`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/substr/) for older releases.

You also want to [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) on `"name"` instead and use the [`$min`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/min/) and [`$max`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/) accumulators for the values.

---

To fix your dates as you really should then you can run something like this:

```
let ops = [];

db.users.find({ "date": { "$type": 2 } }).forEach(doc => {
  let dt = new Date(
    `${doc.date.substr(6,4)}/${doc.date.substr(3,2)}/${doc.date.substr(0,2)}`
  );

  ops = [
    ...ops,
    {
      "updateOne": {
        "filter": { "_id": doc._id },
        "update": { "$set": { "date": dt } }
      }
    }
  ];

  if ( ops.length >= 500 ) {
    db.users.bulkWrite(ops);
    ops = [];
  }
});

if ( ops.length > 0 ) {
  db.users.bulkWrite(ops);
  ops = [];
}
```

Comment: This taught me using BSON date format from now on. Thanks a lot!